# How can we use Bluestacks android emulator for testing Kivy app buildozer?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, bluestacks

I want to use Bluestacks for testing and debugging my Kivy app with Buildozer. So, please guide me how to use Bluestacks for debugging Kivy app

**I'm using Google Colab for debugging** If other methods are possible, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: - This method doesn't use Colab but it does allow you to use the same functionality of `adb` to view the log for debugging purposes

Bluestacks comes pre-installed with a debugging tool which is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks`

I'm pretty sure  that you can view the log of Bluestacks and the apps it is running using said file with the following commands.

```sh
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks"
HD-Adb.exe logcat
```